# Drupal Audio with Audio module or other

Tags: php, drupal, audio, media

I tried the Audio module at http://www.drupal.org/project/audio but I'm looking for alternatives if better ones exist.

- My problem with the Audio module is that the current release (and the past 5 releases) seem to have all been released as `unsable`.
- The second problem is that the player itself that plays the audio is not showing when I display the node. I thought it was a theme problem, but when reverting back to Garland, the player is still invisible.

Any solutions or alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say much about a module from it's release names. Some module developers don't like to release *stable* releases, as they then are saying, this module is bug free. They don't have the same commitment if user's should have issues, as the module is a unstable version. There have been talks about making a guideline/codex for module development and when modules should be regarded as stable releases.

Anyways in your example, if you look at the usage of the project, you'll find that July 4th had 2,958 sites using the 6.x branch of the module. that's a fairly high number, so you shouldn't worry too much about the module being all that unstable.

Your problem with the player, could be a theming / settings issue. If you want help with that, you should write a more specific question about that, including what you've tried/done etc.

Comment: Thanks googletorp. It turned out to be a problem with the file itself I was using, not sure how, but when I used another one, the player became visible.